# UINagivation Bar is moving upside when keyboard will show method calls?

Tags: ios

I am editing UITableview cells, But during editing I am calling Keyboard will show method. After it class Textfield Moves above successfully. But I don't to move UINavigationBar.
How can I achieve That.

Thanks

Following code I am using:

```
if (KeyboardShowStatus) {

    NSNumber *duration = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber *curve = [note.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
    // get a rect for the textView frame
    CGRect containerFrame;
    if ([DataProvider sameInstance].systemVersion < 7) {

        containerFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x,20,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height);
        containerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - containerFrame.size.height + 20;

    }
    else
    {
        containerFrame = self.view.frame;
        containerFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height - containerFrame.size.height;
    }

    // animations settings
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[curve intValue]];

    // set views with new info
    self.view.frame = containerFrame;

    // commit animations
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `UITextField` and other control under one more view of main `UIView`, and change that view's `Y` position.

You storyboard structure look like,

- ViewContrller

  - UIView

    - ViewToMove              //Can Use Simple UIView or ScrollView to change scroll content position.

      - TextField
      - OtherCotrols

Now In you code change some line at last like,

```
// animations settings
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration doubleValue]];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:[curve intValue]];

// set views with new info
self.ViewToMove.frame = containerFrame;

// commit animations
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope this help you.

Enjoy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

- If you are embracing `UITableViewController` keyboard should move your 
  cells up automatically. And if this true, probably it makes sense to 
  setup the `accessoryView` property of your `UITextField` object so it
  appears above the keyboard. It may let avoid using a toolbar
  altogether.
- If you are embracing a simple `UIViewController` or any       other that doesn't support scrolling it may be worth looking at the
  following tiny library: [IHKeyboardAvoing](https://github.com/IdleHandsApps/IHKeyboardAvoiding)